# Use PDF.js based PDF preview viewer to CakePHP 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, pdf, pdf.js

im kind of new to cakephp and Im trying to use this very nice PDF preview I found online https://gist.github.com/ichord/9808444

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.4.1/processing-api.min.js"></script><html>
<!--
  Created using jsbin.com
  Source can be edited via http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/8598/edit
-->
<body>
  <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
  <input id='pdf' type='file'/>

  <!-- Use latest PDF.js build from Github -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //
    // Disable workers to avoid yet another cross-origin issue (workers need the URL of
    // the script to be loaded, and dynamically loading a cross-origin script does
    // not work)
    //
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    //
    // Asynchronous download PDF as an ArrayBuffer
    //
    var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf');
    pdf.onchange = function(ev) {
      if (file = document.getElementById('pdf').files[0]) {
        fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(ev) {
          console.log(ev);
          PDFJS.getDocument(fileReader.result).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
            //
            // Fetch the first page
            //
            console.log(pdf)
            pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
              var scale = 0.8;
              var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
              //
              // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
              //
              var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
              var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
              canvas.height = viewport.height;
              canvas.width = viewport.width;
              //
              // Render PDF page into canvas context
              //
              var task = page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport})
              task.promise.then(function(){
                console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
              });
            });
          }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
          });
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }
    }
            alert(file.name)
  </script>
  

<style id="jsbin-css">
</style>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>​
```

but I cant make it to work with cakephp.

It works on my sever outside the cakephp environment, I guess I have to use it as plugin something but I cant figure it out. It uses the pdf.js and the processing-api.js libraries and I think the problem is loading these libraries.

What I want is that the user preview the pdf he wants to upload before he/she uploads it

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: seems like the problem is with the redirections, when I debug I see that pdf.js send this error: expected expression, got '<'  <!DOCTYPE html> like trying to read the index.php because cakephp redirects it to that file... this happens here PDFJS.getDocument(fileReader.result)

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the solution for this, I added: 
**PDFJS.workerSrc = '/js/pdf.worker.js';** 
before PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

now it works!